# Symfony - Overwrite entity_widget

Tags: symfony

I have table with categories and instead of having name column for every language, I'm storing translations so it looks like this:

```
1   2   category.macbook_12.name    img-12  category.macbook_12.title   category.macbook_12.title   macbook-12.jpg  0
2       category.macbook.name   macbook category.macbook.title  category.macbook.description    macbook.jpg 0
3   2   category.macbook_air.name   macbook-air category.macbook_air.title  category.macbook_air.description    macbook-air.jpg 0
4   3   category.macbook_air_11.name    macbook-air-11  category.macbook_air_11.title   category.macbook_air_11.description macbook-air-11.jpg  0
5   3   category.macbook_air_13.name    macbook-air-13  category.macbook_air_13.title   category.macbook_air_13.description macbook-air-13.jpg  0
6   2   category.macbook_pro.name   macbook-pro category.macbook_pro.title  category.macbook_pro.description    macbook-pro.jpg 0
7   6   category.macbook_pro_13.name    macbook-pro-13  category.macbook_pro_13.title   category.macbook_pro_13.description macbook-pro-13.jpg  0
....
```

I'm trying to create form with entity field. Like this:

```
->add('categories', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Category::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'placeholder' => 'form.product.category.placeholder'
            ])
```

It's not translating name categories but without translating them.

I think, I should customise entity_widget and add |trans to it, but I can't find original one so I can edit it, because I'm not sure how to fetch data from entity.

Where can I find original entity_widget? 
Or is there another way to force translating?

Thanks

Comment: In which file are stored your translations ?

Comment: @DOZ category.yml

Comment: you need to put your translation in messages.LANG.yml for translate your placeholder

Comment: It was first I tried, and it's working if I call in in twig `{{ .'category.macbook_air_13.name' | trans }}` But still not working from formbuilder. I think I should update entity_widget to force translating like this `{{ .entity.data | trans({}, 'message') }}`. But I don't know how original widget looks like, and can't find it.

Comment: @user8810516 EntityType was inherited from ChoiceType, see on choice_widget. You don't need to customize it, cause it already have `|trans`.

Comment: Check for missing translations in the profiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to translate choices in your form, you can set

`choice_translation_domain => 'messages'`.

Your translations MUST be in directory

> - the `app/Resources/translations` directory;
> - the `app/Resources/<bundle_name>/translations` directory;
> - the `Resources/translations/` directory inside of any bundle.

[via Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/translation.html#translation-resource-locations)

and stored in file `messages.{NEEDED_LANGUAGE}.yml` as @DOZ said.

NEEDED_LANGUAGE can be short (en, de, ru, pl) or long (en_US, en_AU, en_GB).

Also you can name your translations as you want, but with NEEDED_LANGUAGE notation. So your category.yml file must be named category.en.yml and must stored in translations directory.

For using translations from your custom file, u must set translation_domain and choice_translation_domain manually on each field or in twig file globaly.

```
# src/{BUNDLE_NAME}/Resources/translations/messages.en.yml (based on symfony version)
category:
    macbook_12.name: "Macbook 12"
    macbook_12.title: "Macbook 12` laptop"
    macbook.name: "Macbook"
    macbook.title: "Macbook laptop"
form.product.category.placeholder: "Awesome macbooks here!"
# ... and yet
```